# gradle task will run when use AS sync

Tags: android, gradle

i create a task dependsOn assembleRelease like this code in app/build.gradle, and get an `FileNotFoundException` error when i use AS sync

```
task push(type: Exec, dependsOn: ['assembleRelease']) {
    println 'push invoke'
    def apkDir = "${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/build/outputs/plugin/release/"
    def apkName = ""
    fileTree(apkDir).visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
        println "${details.name}"
        //只取第一个apk
        if (apkName.endsWith(".apk")) {
            apkName = details.name
            details.stopVisiting()
        }
    }
    if (apkName.isEmpty()) throw new FileNotFoundException("apk file not found,please invoke 'assemblePlugin' first")
    workingDir project.projectDir
    commandLine 'adb', 'push', "${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/build/outputs/plugin/release/{$apkName}", '/sdcard/Demo_plugin_1.apk'
    ignoreExitValue true
}
```

the code will run when I sync gradle?
and I want the code will run when excute `gradlew push`
what should I do

Answer (score 0):

try to use doFirst{ } block for the first part of the task:

```
doFirst {
    println 'push invoke'
    def apkDir = "${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/build/outputs/plugin/release/"
    def apkName = ""
    fileTree(apkDir).visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
        println "${details.name}"
        //只取第一个apk
        if (apkName.endsWith(".apk")) {
            apkName = details.name
            details.stopVisiting()
        }
    }
    if (apkName.isEmpty()) throw new FileNotFoundException("apk file not found,please 
     invoke 'assemblePlugin' first")
}
```